# I cannot install Ubuntu on my PC (Asrockp4v88)

Tags: installation, boot, live-cd

I cannot install Ubuntu. When I insert the installation CD in DVD-ROM, my computer does boot from CD and automatically run Windows. I even tried to boot manually from CD but it does not work. My friend told me to use a new DVD-ROM, so I tried it but it does not work too.

System specs:

- Motherboard: Asrock p4v88
- CPU is Intel P4 Celeron 2.3GHz
- 786MB RAM

Comment: You did try to adjust the BIOS options?

Comment: yes I try it but it did not work

Comment: Is your CD image corrputed?

Comment: No it is not.I even change cd.

Answer (score 0):

First, please check if your ISO image is corrupted. Go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM to do so. Then make sure you burn the CD at the slowest speed. If it still cannot boot, then maybe it's a hardware problem.

Comment: I think it is hardware problem.But I can open cd from windows and autorun is also active.

Comment: Hmm.... Really weird. Try to use Wubi then.

Comment: please help me I really want to instal ubuntu and get out of windows.

Comment: I try to use Wubi,it says to reboot computer.But when I reboot nothig have happended.I only see a slash(-) is flashing and I hear that the DVDROM is challenging to boot from cd.I wait 5 hours yesterday,but nothing have happened.